# Taxi ride from Lima airport to Miraflores

Tags: peru, taxis, lima

How much would it cost for a taxi ride from Lima Airport to the Miraflores district? The plane lands after midnight, so, if applicable, there might be a night fare.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I just called the 3 taxi companies that work with the airport and the cost is around 60 soles (23 dollar), which i think is a fair price because it's a service of the airport and it's safe. You could take the taxi outside and the cost would be 40 soles or maybe less but i can't say anything about safety.

Price details:

```
1 - 3 person (Car)   60 soles
4 - 6 person (Van)   90 soles
```

Answer (score 4):

A fare price for a taxicab from Lima airport to Miraflores would be S/. 55 soles and no more, the ride is about 45 minutes and it depends on the time and traffic, in the rush hour the traffic is terrible. I booked my taxi online before heading to Lima with www.taxidatum.com, they have fixed rates and published online.

Answer (score 3):

When we were there last June, the cost from the airport to Miraflores was about 60 soles. We were not able to get them lower than 55 soles, and that was like pulling teeth, so I think they keep their prices pretty firmly at about 60 soles.

Answer (score 0):

Prices as of December 2019, at 1 AM, to go from Lima airport ([Jorge Chavez International Airport, LIM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jorge_Ch%C3%A1vez_International_Airport)) to  [Kennedy Park](https://www.google.com/search?q=kennedy+park+in+miraflores%2C+lima) in  [Miraflores District, Lima](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miraflores_District,_Lima):

- Taxi Green (1 passenger, perhaps more is possible, I haven't asked): 60 PEN
- Uber (1 to 4 passengers): 35 PEN (see [How to get an Uber at Lima airport?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/150850/1810))

Note that these prices include the 12.20 PEN Jorge Chavez Airport Surcharge. I'm guessing that if you walk outside the airport and don't get robbed before getting the taxi, you might save 12.20 PEN.

Duration: 35 minutes.